# I made a CPP measuring script and what should I add to my script to skip the unmeasurable files and keep the script running?

Tags: praat

I made CPP measuring script in Praat. If even one of the files is unmeasurable, the script will stop running. How do I change the code below to allow the praat to skip the unmeasurable files and leave the result blank, and keep the script running on the rest of the files?

```
form
    comment Directory of sound files 
    text sound_directory /Directory
    word soundfileExtension_(with_dot) .wav
    comment Full path of the resulting text file:
    text resultfile /Directory/x.txt
endform

fileappend 'resultfile$' fileName'tab$'syllable'tab$'cppValue'newline$'

Create Strings as file list... soundfileListObj 'sound_directory$'/*'soundfileExtension$'
numFiles = Get number of strings
pause 'numFiles' sound files identified. Continue?

for iFile to numFiles

    select Strings soundfileListObj
    soundName$ = Get string... iFile

    Read from file... 'sound_directory$'/'soundName$'
    Rename... soundObj

    #measuring CPP
    To Spectrum... yes
    To PowerCepstrum
    cppValue = Get peak prominence: 60, 333.3, "Parabolic", 0.001, 0.05, "Exponential decay", "Robust slow"

    fileappend "'resultfile$'" 'soundName$''tab$''cppValue''newline$'
    
    select all
    minus Strings soundfileListObj
    Remove

endfor


select all
Remove
#### END OF SCRIPT ####
```